# Can we pass object as param in sql like array to prevent sql injection in nodejs using promise-mysql module

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

I want to pass an object to a SQL query.

I know this works:

```
connection.query('SELECT * FROM projects WHERE status = ?',
    ['active']
)
```

What is the correct syntax to use named object properties as parameters instead?  Something like this:

```
connection.query('SELECT * FROM projects WHERE status = :status ',
    { status: 'active' }
)
```

Comment: I'm not sure the API supports what you have in mind, as the second parameter needs to be an array of values to bind.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  Ok,Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This possibility is not available out-of-the-box, but the [documentation](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#custom-format) of mysqljs (which promise-mysql relies on) explains how this can be achieved by assigning a custom function to `connection.config.queryFormat`:

> If you prefer to have another type of query escape format, there's a
>   connection configuration option you can use to define a custom format
>   function. You can access the connection object if you want to use the
>   built-in .escape() or any other connection function.
>
> Here's an example of how to implement another format:
>
> ```
> connection.config.queryFormat = function (query, values) {
>   if (!values) return query;
>   return query.replace(/\:(\w+)/g, function (txt, key) {
>     if (values.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
>       return this.escape(values[key]);
>     }
>     return txt;
>   }.bind(this));
> };
>
> connection.query("UPDATE posts SET title = :title", { title: "Hello MySQL" });
> ```